# Dialogflow response from webhook using flask python integration platform digital human uneeq

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to send a response to Dialogflow Es using webhook written in python-flask.
Integration platform :
digital human --> Uneeq

I tried with the fulfillment library (dialogflow_fulfillment) but it was not working so I tried it without a library like :

```
if req.get('queryResult').get('action') == 'appointment':
    print("ïntent triggered")
    return {"fulfillmentText": 'BUDDY!'}
```

It worked!

Now the issue is before integrating this chatbot to digital human I wrote the whole code using the fulfillment library. Now I need to change the whole code for this purpose.
As I am unable to extract entities using context-based intents (session-vars) like :

```
case = agent.context.get('session-vars').get('parameters').get('case')
name = agent.context.get('session-vars').get('parameters').get('name')['name']
email = agent.context.get('session-vars').get('parameters').get('email')
phone = agent.context.get('session-vars').get('parameters').get('phone')
```

So my question is how to accomplish this task successfully?
If I try to use the fulfillment library then how to send a response to Dialogflow so that digital human will understand it since "agent.add" doesn't work.
Or, If I try to do it without a library then how to extract entities(from the session-vars) like (case, name, email, phone).

I need to save all these parameters(entities) in firebase, These output context (only session-vars parameters not other contexts):
[image: fulfillment request]

This is the response I am getting correctly without library:
[image: fulfillment response]

Unable to proceed at any cost!
looking forward to your response.
Thanks in advance!

Complete code (with the library):

```
from dialogflow_fulfillment import WebhookClient
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

def handler(agent: WebhookClient) :
    """Handle the webhook request.."""

    req = request.get_json(force=True)
    a= req.get('queryResult').get('action')
    if req.get('queryResult').get('action') == 'appointment':  
        name =  agent.context.get('session-vars').get('parameters').get('name')['name']
        email =  agent.context.get('session-vars').get('parameters').get('email')
        phone =  agent.context.get('session-vars').get('parameters').get('phone')        
        print("ïntent triggered")
        agent.add('BUDDY!')
    
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(force=True)
    agent = WebhookClient(req)
    agent.handle_request(handler)
    return agent.response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Complete code (without library):

```
import urllib
import json
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

# Flask app should start in global layout
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    res = makeWebhookResult(req)
    res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)
    r = make_response(res)
    #print(res)
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return r

def makeWebhookResult(req):

    intent_name = req.get('queryResult').get('intent').get('displayName')
    print(intent_name)
    action_name = req['queryResult']['action']
    if req.get('queryResult').get('action') == 'input.welcome':
        print("intent trigered")
        return {"fulfillmentText": 'Hi there'}

    if action_name == 'test':
        cont = req.get('queryResult').get('outputContexts')[0]['name']
        print(type(cont))
        x = cont.split("/")
        print(x[6])
        if x[6] == 'session-vars' :
            para = req['queryResult']['outputContexts']
            print(para)
            print("test intent trigered")
            return {"fulfillmentText": 'Bye there'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Why do you use `get` instead of the normal and Pythonic `req['queryResult']['action']`?

Comment: Yeah, This also works. Is there any issue with using ```get``` ?

Comment: If you are getting my issue please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: I just wanna get these parameters (name, pwd) set by using session-vars from Dialogflow :
{"queryResult": {
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/f4-pxsn/agent/sessions/19d704ac-288d-0e30-36f1-da37518616c0/contexts/session-vars",
        "parameters": {
          "name": {
            "name": "sana"
          },
          "pwd": "454455665"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
@TimRoberts

Comment: You haven't said what isn't working.  Are you getting the structure you expect in `webhook`?  Are you printing your variables so you can tell that?  There's no issue with `get` except that it isn't normal to writ it that way.

Comment: Yeah I am getting my all parameters using agent.context.get('session-vars').get('parameters').get('email'). But i want to get these parameters without using dialogflow fulfilment library. Reason : I am unable to integrate this chatbot to uneeq digital human . [link](https://creator.us.uneeq.io/try/a2d1391e-a9d0-4a39-bb46-40dd7cb2fa7f)

Comment: I get that.  What are you getting without the library?  Who is calling you in that case?

Comment: agent.add('Hi thereReady to get started?') is not working for uneeq. Whereas it works for all integration platforms. I am a beginner and tried my best to describe my problem if still there is an issue you can ask me i will elaborate it more.

Comment: With library digital human is unable to speak.

Comment: And without library I tried a simple greeting message like :
return {"fulfillmentText": ''Hi thereReady to get started?"}
It works for digital human.

Comment: Well, then, your non-library example should be doing the same thing.  Do you see "intent triggered" when you make a request?

Comment: Yeah, the intent is triggered I also get a response on Dialogflow Console but digital human is unable to speak that greeting.

Comment: I have recorded a short video for you to clear this issue:
[link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/5547703?key=22de6290dcafcbaed09b6d168966b7cd)
Please Check this

Comment: Also please Check this image [link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/14707340?key=e328fb9fc145c63dd31c88c06b3c0b1a) Intent is triggered in both cases with and without a library. But when I test it with a digital human with a library There is no response you can check this in the image clearly. But when I trigger this intent without library it is giving response in dialogflow (history) plus digital human is also speaking.
I hope this will clear you. @TimRoberts

Comment: Why do you think the WebHook client will return the JSON string you need?

Comment: I just want all these details name, email,pwd, etc. As I need to save it to firebase.
Case: when a user starts talking to a digital human. She will ask name, email, pwd, etc one by one, and then all these parameters details should be saved in firebase. I trained these intents in Dialogflow and using output context, session-vars I was getting that response with the fulfillment library. All worked fine. But now the issue is digital human is unable to recognize if I send greetings with the library. So I need to change the whole code. I need to do it without library. So How can I do this?

Comment: You said it didn't work with the library, but it works without, and that's what you wanted.  Is that not correct?

Comment: Yes digital human didn't work with the library. I have also made a short demo video [link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/5547703?key=22de6290dcafcbaed09b6d168966b7cd) This will help you to understand the issue

Comment: Problem :
The digital human didn't work with the library. And without the library, I AM UNABLE TO ACCESS (parameters of session-vars)  in Dialogflow. By using a library, It can be accessed easily but If do it with a library then digital human didn't work. So How should I do no so that I can access those parameters as I need to save all parameters like name,age,pwd etc onm firebase. @TimRoberts

Comment: Don't know.  The JSON returned by the library is not the same as what your Flask app returns.  It would be `{'fulfillmentText': {'Text': {'Text': 'BUDDY!' } } }`, which is what the DialogFlow API requires.

Comment: I have added a picture in this post Please check it may be you will get it.

Comment: You've now shown a response that worked, but what is the response when it doesn't work?

Comment: Ok I will show it.